# vuetify data-table insert input on th

Tags: vuetify.js

I am trying to insert input on data-table's all th element.

```
 <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" item-key="name" show-select>
  <template v-slot:header> 
   <v-text-field hide-details="auto" flat solo class="float-input"></v-text-field>
  </template> 
 </v-data-table>
```

This is not working. How do I fix the code? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You above code is working, you can debug in developers console, the
> component is placed next to the headers row but only in the first column, to view your input filed
> you can add a label attribute to input field

If you want to add text field to each header, then you need to include props.headers and loop in header slot

Please find the below code:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" item-key="name" show-select>
  <template v-slot:header> 
   <v-text-field hide-details="auto" flat solo class="float-input" label="some input field in header slot"></v-text-field>
  </template> 
 </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

Please find the working codepen here: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/BapLMyV?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your example, the inputs are located out of TH tag.  How do I put input inside of th tag like this ?   <th>Desert<input></th><th>calories<input></th>

Comment: You have to override the header by constructing header.<column_value> slot, this replce the existing th and you can write your custom code here